# Cannot convert from '.Controllers.AccountController' to 'System.Web.UI.Page' when trying to make "success" message

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

After pressing "submit" button, I need to have success message shown. I'm trying to do it with this line :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "Success", false);
```

The error is :

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'WebApplication2.Controllers.AccountController' to
>   'System.Web.UI.Page'

I've tried looking similar topics, changing 'this' to 'Page' and so on - no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your submit button doing? Which controller action is it submitting to? Can you post your code?

Comment: Seems that you have using MVC controller which may redirects to a legacy ASPX page, can you show view page markup?

Comment: @TejSoft Hello,thank you, I've put the code in the post, can you please take a look?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto hey, I'm not sure what part of the code do you need, can you explain me?

Comment: Show us the web.config inside your `views` folder.

Comment: `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` is the old way of including scripts.  I don't think it works with MVC. You should use the new MVC/Razor constructs to include scripts.

Comment: @Amy please check my EDIT.

Comment: The problem was solved.

Comment: Well your views `web.config` looks fine.  Hm.  Not sure.

Comment: Ah, you can submit your solution as an answer and accept it as the answer after a time period has expired.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved using

```
 TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Registration was successful";
in controller
```

and

```
@{
    var message = TempData["AlertMessage"] ?? string.Empty;
}


<script type="text/javascript">
    var message = '@message';
    if(message)
        alert(message);
</script>
```

in views.